# changing state in another screen changes the state of DrawerNavigation as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Inside my DrawerNavigator, I have Profile screen and many other screens but for the purpose of this question, I will be using my Profile screen as an example. This is how I have set up my DrawerNavigator.

#### Navigation.js

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: DashboardStackNavigator },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileStack },
    Calendar: { screen: CalendarStack },
    Rewards: { screen: RewardsStack },
    FeedbackForm: { screen: FeedbackStack },
    ChangePassword: { screen: ChangePasswordStack },
    Login: { screen: Login },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: ({ navigation }) => <DrawerContainer navigation={navigation} />
  }
);
```

My DrawerContainer fetches data from the WebApi **ProfileDetails** and set the Image that is shown in the DrawerContainer from the fetched data. I would fetch the state, setState of items to the respons and set the Image according to the imageUrl.

#### DrawerContainer.js

```
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
              <Image
                source={{ uri: items[0].imageUrl }}
                style={styles.photo} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

When I press on the image, I will be navigated to the Profile screen, where I can change the ProfileImage as well as other info, such as Bio. Since ProfileImage will only be shown in the Drawer Navigator, I wil just Image for this question.

#### Profile.js

Just like the DrawerNavigator, the Profile screen will also fetch its data from the WebApi **ProfileDetails** and displayes the Image according to the imageUrl. The SelectImage() calls a function for users to open up the gallery and choose a new image.

After choosing the Image, users will press the save button which will UPDATE the value of imageUrl to the new image link.

```
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.selectImage()}>
            <View style={styles.piccontainer}>
              <Image
                source={{ uri: this.state.items[0].imageUrl }}
                style={styles.photo} />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => {
                this.uploadImage();
                this.goBack()
              }}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Save</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

//uploadImage(), uploading image to s3 and updating the link in my webapi
uploadImage = () => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    })
    let file = this.state.file;
    let config = this.state.config;
    const { navigation } = this.props
    RNS3.put(file, config)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          items: this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
            i == 0 ?
              { ...item, imageUrl: response.headers.Location } : item),
          params: {
            ImageUrl: response.headers.Location,
            EmployeeBio: this.state.items[0].employeeBio
          },
        }, () => { this.updateProfileData(this.state.params) })
      })
  }

//goBack(), return to previous screen
goBack = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
  }
```

When this happens, I would like to update the Image at the DrawerContainer as well, but am unable to do so. I have also addListener to DrawerContainer, but it seems to not update the Image. Is there any way I can do to show the updated Image in the DrawerContainer?

#### DrawerContainer.js

These are added to DrawerContainer but it still is not working.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      this.getProfileData();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }
```

Comment: are you using redux . with your app ???

Comment: I have it installed, but i'm unsure on how to use it. I have already set Providers and store in my app.js

Comment: try to learn redux and it'll provide store which can be accessible in any component and you can use your data and update your data.this  will automatically replace everywhere in your app

Comment: @PrakashKarena hey! I just learnt redux, but i'm having problems changing the state and posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901275/changing-state-using-mapdispatchtoprops)