# change to new value of state using mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

#### Profile.js

The Profile screen fetches its data from the WebApi using redux and displayes the Image according to the imageUrl. The SelectImage() calls a function for users to open up the gallery and choose a new image.

After choosing the Image, I would like the image to be shown on the screen and replace current value of `this.props.items.imageUrl`. I just started redux and implemented it to my application. I would like to update the state of redux and be accessed on other screens as well, as the picture will be shown in other screens as well. However, I am unable to change the Image inside the app.

All the data is inside **items**

```
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.selectImage()}>
            <View style={styles.piccontainer}>
              <Image
                source={{ uri: this.props.items.imageUrl }}
                style={styles.photo} />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => {
                this.uploadImage();
                this.goBack()
              }}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Save</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is my selectImage() function

```
  selectImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });
    let file = result.uri
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.updatePicture(file)
    }
  }
```

I believe that i have to `mapDispatchToProps` to call an action.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updatePicture: file => {dispatch(updatePicture(file))}
  }
}
```

I'm lost after calling the function, do I put the reducers and actions in the same place as I put the function that fetches profile data? Do i create a new file, but if i do so, what do i set the initial state as? Thank you for the help. I appreciate it alot.

#### profileReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  profilepic: '',
};

export default function updateprofileReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PICTURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profilepic: action.payload.file
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### profileAction.js

```
export const updatePicture = file => ({
    type: UPDATE_PICTURE,
    payload: file
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in the reducer:

```
    case UPDATE_PICTURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profilepic: action.payload, // <--- this instead of action.payload.file 
      }
```

and since you didn't mention, you will need to mapStateToProps to map your profilepic state in redux to your prop.

but here bring up another issue, your props is in the format of object (items.imageUrl). but your state is just a string (profilepic). Unless you mean to make a profilepic an object which store an items of profilepic images which your reducer is not doing that, you will need to fix that. Or otherwise, if you mean to store only one image url at a time, you need to map the redux state to a new prop and set the init value to be your items.imageUrl value.

EDIT: base on what OP clarified, here is some more sample code, note: since i don't have the whole piece of code so I don't know is there any helper method to inject the new reducer to the store and set the init value. that's prefer method but just for showing the idea of mapStateToProps:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectImage()}>
  <View style={styles.piccontainer}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: this.props.imageUrlFromRedux || this.props.items.imageUrl }}
      style={styles.photo}
    />
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and then you have define the mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  imageUrlFromRedux: state.profilepic,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

hope this help. and please remember to fix your reducer

Comment: Hey! What I actually would like to do  is set the new selected Image as items.ImageUrl, I can't seem to do it, so i put ```profilepic``` at UPDATE_PICTURE. May i know what i should do so that after I change the pic, ```items.ImageUrl``` gets updated and the new selected Image is shown?

Comment: So it is best practice to keep your props immutable. aka not changing it pass down. So instead of thinking changing items.ImageUrl to the new value, maybe you think the other way around, to set your init value to items.ImageUrl and then when the button click, you update that value. That's what i mean.

Unless you really need to change the props value and bubble it back up to the parent, that's a total different issue. But for what i see what you try to archive is what i described here. use mapStateToProp

Comment: I just found out that ```this.updatePicture(file)``` is also causing an error, saying that ```this.props.dispatch is not a function```, I seem to not be able to call dispatch functions there. How can i fix this?

I've also tried adding it in my TouchableOpacity
```onPress={() =>{this.selectImage(); this.updatePicture()}```, but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You should add some changes

**profileAction.js**

```
export const profileAction = file => ({
    type: UPDATE_PICTURE,
    payload: file
})
```

**profileReducer.js**

```
import {profileAction} from 'profileAction.js';

export function updatePicture (file) {
    return (dispatch)=> {
        //some action with file
        dispatch(profileAction(file)); 
    };
}

export default function updateprofileReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PICTURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profilepic: action.payload.file
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

then import updatePicture in your react file, connect with your react class like this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Replace mapDispatchToprops like this

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updatePicture: file => dispatch(updatePicture(file))
  }
}
```

You have mistake in your **selectImage** function. You should replace this code fragment like this

```
 if(!result.cancelled) {
      this.props.updatePicture(file);
  }
```

Your updatePicture function is available only from props.